# Class initialization with many Include Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I put too many parameters (Include()) into my User Class. My User class becomes unstable and right now my user table is null.

It worked fine with just 2 parameters.

Controllers

```
var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Annees).Include(u => u.Genres).Include(u => u.Jours).Include(u => u.Mois_ss);

        return View(users.ToList());
```

Models

```
      public int? GenreId { get; set; }
            public virtual Genre Genres { get; set; }

            public int? JourId { get; set; }
            public virtual Jour Jours { get; set; }

            public int? MoisId { get; set; }
            public virtual Mois Mois_ss { get; set; }

            public int? AnneeId { get; set; }
            public virtual Annee Annees { get; set; }
```

ETC..

I also have a Class initialization which is working fine with few parameters:

```
public class ProjectInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProjectContext>
```

I hope I was clear :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'unstable'?

Comment: Are you using `Entity Framework`? If so please add a tag indicating such.

Comment: sometime i got this error : [Win32Exception (0x80004005)] when I tried to get the list of user. And it was working fine before.

Comment: and sometime my DB User become empty, even if I have a initialization class with 2 users.

Comment: Can you give us the inner exception, if there is one?

Comment: Right now, the error is gone but my user table is empty. I will try to give you more information about the error if it come back. besides I put the last version of entity framework but it didn t change anything.

Comment: My class ProjectInitializer give me the error HResult=-2146233087,when i tried to change my DB. don t think there is Inner exception

Comment: à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
à System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
à ~.Models.ProjectInitializer.Seed(ProjectContext context) dans c:\~~\Models\ProjectInitializer.cs:ligne 308
       à System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
       à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)